# Аглоритм заполнения площади прямоугольниками по диагонали | C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

я пытаюсь сделать алгоритм заполнения площади (обычный квадрат допустим), другими квадратами произвольного размера, я прикрепил изображение для более ясного понятия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим у меня есть вектор с n квадратами, в векторе хранится SIZE (cx, cy) каждого квадрата, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Квадраты или прямоугольники?

Comment: Прямоугольники, извиняюсь

Comment: Здесь какая-то практическая необходимость? Вы не текстурный атлас так делаете случайно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, я пытаюсь сделать текстурный алтас из символов.

Comment: О, паучье чутье меня не подвело. А почему именно по диагонали? Есть замечательная маленькая библиотечка [stb_rect_pack](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_rect_pack.h), но она прижимает прямоугольники к вехрней границе.

Comment: Мне показалось это самым правильным решением, буду пробовать работать с этой библиотекой.

Comment: Вот вам еще для общего развития: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/215103)

Comment: Атласы обычно делаются через bin-packing, и не совсем по диагонали.